# The style is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi everyone I want when I click that the heart fills up and becomes red or it is empty and is black, only I can't achieve this result, neither the color nor the shape of the heart changes when I click on it. Can you help me?

```
function Discussion(props) {
  const [heartTouched, setHeartTouched] = useState(new Array(DATA.length));

  const NewArray = (id, value) => {
    let array = heartTouched;
    array[id] = value;
    setHeartTouched(array);
    console.log(heartTouched);
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#F3D26F" }}
      data={DATA}
      extraData={DATA}
      keyExtractor={({ id }) => id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <Screen style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.commentContainer}>
            <View style={styles.textCommentContainer}>
              <Text>{item.user}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.comment}>Hello</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.heartContainer}
              onPress={
                index === item.id - 1
                  ? heartTouched[index]
                    ? () => NewArray(index, false) + (item.like -= 1)
                    : () => NewArray(index, true) + (item.like += 1)
                  : null
              }
            >
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                style={styles.heartStyle}
                name={heartTouched[index] ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
                color={heartTouched[index] ? "red" : "black"}
                size={24}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Screen>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mostly is from the line

```
   let array = heartTouched;
```

When you need to change the state in react you have to do it in an immutable way,
meaning that you can't take the array and change one element, you have to recreate a new one, then change the new one.

```
  let array = [...heartTouched];
```

React only trigger rerender when the state (if it was an array or object), is recreated, because it looks at the reference not the object, and when you change one element you are not changing the reference.

This way you are creating a new array from the state, hope this works for you.